Automatically make table with de-aligned rows
I'm working on a package that includes re-mappings of lots of maps. I'd like those re-mappings to be automatically displayed in a table in the org-document I'm writing the documentation in, which isn't too hard if I'm using some embedded code and org-table-convert-region. I have a pretty good idea of how to do it for the most part. The trouble is that on a standard QWERTY-keyboard the lower key row is de-aligned with the middle row in such a way that the B-key is almost precisely between the G-key and the H-key. My layout actually uses this alignment and it should be reflected in the table. But I don't know how to make tables (regardless of whether it's org-tables or tables from table.el) where a row is automatically de-aligned with the other rows in the way the bottom row of the QWERTY-layout is. I also can't just use a macro to de-align the tables once they are done since the exact size of the tables depends on the commands that fill them, which varies. So is there a way to automatically create tables with de-aligned rows like I need them?

Not that I know of.
